# Ref (from useRef) showing up as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I am using the UseRef hook to create a Ref variable and inserting that into one of the components in my return statement. 'AnimationComponent' has it's own `<g></g>` tags which return some inner elements.

The basic outline of my code is like this:

```jsx
var refVar1 = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("value of refVar1 : " + refVar1);
    console.log("value of refVar1.current : " + refVar1.current);
}, [])


return(
  <g>
     <path>
        <AnimationComponent ref={refVar1}>
     </path>
  </g>
)
```

I'm finding that the value of refVar1 and refVar1.current are always undefined.

Which makes me wonder what how is the code really flowing in React? Once 'AnimationComponent' is rendered, does that mean that the code within the useEffect will never execute afterwards?

I always thought all the code in React components is " asynchronous " in a way. Even when inner children components are rendered, the code in the parents will still execute simultaneously?

I have tried putting those console log statements inside UseEffects and outside them. They always show as undefined.

Edit: Sorry, it's only refVar1.current that shows up as undefined. refVar1 shows up as ' [object object] ' on the console.

Comment: Does `AnimationComponent` implement [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)? If so, what does it do with its `ref` prop?

Comment: `refVar1` cannot possibly be `undefined`

Comment: in your case useEffect will be executed only once, since you've an empty dependency array. That means useEffect will only trigger when component is loaded/mounted on screen

Comment: @Phil Sorry my mistake. It's only refVar1.current that shows up as undefined. refVar1 shows up as ' [object object] ' on the console.

Comment: @Booster : So what do I put inside the dependency array to ensure refVar1.current is displayed? Should I put refVar1 itself in the dependency array?

Comment: Given solution as answer, since its difficult to write up in comments

Comment: Can you supply the code for your AnimationComponent? It's impossible to say what is going on without seeing what's happening in there e.g. as mentioned - does it forwardRef? Is it a class component? Is the ref actually forwarded to an intrinsic element?

Comment: @JakeSidSmith I figured out the problem. I was only passing the ref to a component but it never ended up in a native HTML element within that component. I thought that React would automatically associate the inner HTML with the ref, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forwardRef to pass the reference. Here is an example:

Created a simple component which is receiving ref

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const MyComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
});

export default MyComp;
```

Parent component

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import MyComp from "./myComp";

export default function App() {
  const refVar1 = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value of refVar1 : ", refVar1);
    console.log("value of refVar1.current : ", refVar1.current);
  }),
    [];

  return (
    <div >
      <MyComp ref={refVar1} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be executed when `useRef != undefined`. `useEffect` will listen to `refVar.current`, so when `refVar1` is defined your logic will be executed again.

```
    var refVar1 = useRef();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(gridInstance.current){
            console.log("value of refVar1 : " + refVar1);
            console.log("value of refVar1.current : " + refVar1.current);
        }
    }, [refVar1.current])
    
    
    return(
      <g>
         <path>
            <AnimationComponent ref={refVar1}>
         </path>
      </g>
    )
```